# KeyError: "['...'] not in index" possible global/instance variable mixup

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, spyder

I have had this very straight forward code for a while that worked absolutely fine. It uses the raw data straight from the source. The source data is static and hasn't been altered.

I believe that jupyter has allowed my error to go undetected for a while. I believe that it is something to do with me altering the dataframe inside a function and not making a new dataframe. However I am not sure.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
# Convert UTC to datetime & Rename & index
def dt_index(dataframe,UTC_convert = True):
    if UTC_convert:
        # Error traceback to the following line:
        dataframe['UTC Time'] = dataframe['UTC Time'].map(lambda x: datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(x))         
        dataframe.rename(columns={'UTC Time':'datetime'}, inplace=True)
        dataframe.set_index('datetime',drop=True,inplace= True)
    else:
        dataframe.set_index('UTC Time',drop=True,inplace= True)
    return dataframe
```

Call:
`alldata_dt = dt_index(alldata, True)`

Error received:

`KeyError: "['UTC Time'] not in index"`

Comment: It means there is no column `'UTC Time` in `alldata` DataFrame

Comment: Or are you running this twice?  The first time after you load it, it works, then you are running it again with a saved version of this output of this dataframe without relloading the data and running it again (remember Jupyter keeps the fames in memory from saves)...

Comment: Hi Paul, yes it seems to once I have run it twice. However, occasionally even without. What is the proper syntax for altering a dataframe and saving it as a new one, without overwriting the original?

Comment: Just to confirm, UTC Time absolutely exists and is spelt correctly.